# Initialize C struct data member in a C++ wrapper class

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

The essential problem has basically already been answered elsewhere on this site, but what I really want is opinions on the best way to implement my class in terms of practicality and aesthetics, and if there are any subtleties involved. So bearing that in mind, here's my question:

I have a simple encryption program that I've written and now I want to add xz compression to it, which is written in C. The xz code uses a struct to control data in and out of the compression algos:

```
/* All of this is in src/liblzma/api/lzma/base.h if you download version 5.0.3
 * XZ Utils
 */
typedef struct {
    const uint8_t *next_in;
    size_t avail_in;
    uint64_t total_in;
    /* ...
     * and so on. Some other members are enums and other structs, but
     * this is basically a POD structure
     */
} lzma_stream;

/* This macro is used to initialize lzma_stream objects */
#define LZMA_STREAM_INIT \
    { NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, \
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
    LZMA_RESERVED_ENUM, LZMA_RESERVED_ENUM }

/* Here's LZMA_RESERVED_ENUM in case anyone's wondering: */
typedef enum {
    LZMA_RESERVED_ENUM = 0
} lzma_reserved_enum;
```

I have a wrapper class to lzma_stream so that if my encryption code throws, the wrapper class destructor can call functions that deallocate any assigned memory in the lzma_stream struct. So, I have:

```
class Stream {
public:
    Stream();
    ~Stream();
    void init();
    // ...
private:
    lzma_stream stream_;
    // ...
};

Stream::~Stream() {
    lzma_end( &stream_ );
}
```

My question is, how would *you* initialize `Stream::stream_` and why? I could initialize the struct's members individually:

```
Stream::Stream() : stream_(), ... {}

void Stream::init() {
    stream_.next_in = NULL;
    stream_.avail_in = 0;
    // ...
}
```

But I would like to use `LZMA_STREAM_INIT` because that would mean that I would not need to worry about changes in the xz library. With that in mind, alternatively, I could create a temp:

```
Stream::Stream() : stream_(), ... {}

void Stream::init() {
    lzma_stream const temp = LZMA_STREAM_INIT;
    stream_ = temp;
    // ...
}
```

Preliminary question: Is there a way I could do the initialization in the `Stream` ctor (edit: I mean, in the initialization list)? (I take it not, right?) I'm trying to avoid c++0x initialization lists, by the way, for compiler portability reasons.

As I said above, these are they ways to solve the problem and that's already been said elsewhere; but what I'd like to know is which way would you guys do it (if there's not some other way I don't know about)? I can already guess that you'd say the latter method, but I have the sneaky feeling that there's a catch involved: is there?

**OK, lots of useful info and solutions provided below. Thanks for all help, guys.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the *ctor-initializer*, you just need to add a helper function:

```
Stream::Stream() : stream_(def_stream) {}

static lzma_stream def_stream()
{
  lzma_stream tmpStream = LZMA_STREAM_INIT;
  return tmpStream;
}
```

Among other things, this allows you to initialize a const aggregate member.  And almost all compilers will elide creation of the temporary.

If you run into a compiler that doesn't, you can use this variation:

```
static const lzma_stream& def_stream()
{
  static lzma_stream tmpStream = LZMA_STREAM_INIT;
  return tmpStream;
}
```

In C++0x, you'll be able to write:

```
Stream::Stream() : stream_ LZMA_STREAM_INIT {}
```

which takes advantage of the "uniform initializer syntax".

Comment: (Yeah, that feature of the c++0x standard would make things a bit easier!) OK, that makes sense. You've written `def_stream` as independent of the class: if you meant that (excuse my naivety), is there any reason the function is static? Even if the helper function were a static member function, is there a reason I'd make it so? Couldn't I just make it a private (or protected) member function? Or am I completely wrong/missing the point?

Comment: @Zorawar: I intended it to be read as a static member function, probably private.  It has to be static, because an instance member function requires an instance to call it with, and no instance exists yet.  Of course a global function would work too.

Comment: Right, of course. (Interestingly, though, I declared it as a normal class method and neither GCC, Clang, or the Intel compiler flagged this as an error. It didn't even crash at runtime, and the values *seem* init'd properly. I guess it's a case of undefined behaviour, then, and not relying on this to work.)

Comment: @Zorawar: Actually, it's ok, as long as it's used to initialize a member and not a base class.  "Member functions (including virtual member functions, 10.3) can be called for an object under construction. Similarly, an object under construction can be the operand of the `typeid` operator (5.2.8) or of a `dynamic_cast` (5.2.7). However, if these operations are performed in a *ctor-initializer* (or in a function called directly
or indirectly from a *ctor-initializer*) before all the *mem-initializers* for base classes have completed, the result
of the operation is undefined."

Comment: But since it doesn't depend on the current instance, it's still better to make it static.

Comment: Again, that makes sense. Thanks for the info. I'll think I'll wrap this up soon, being fairly satisfied with all the responses to my questions.

Comment: Your code to set stream_ didn't work for me; my compiler complained lzma_stream doesn't have a lzma_stream (*)(void) constructor.  But I find if you change it to stream_(def_stream()) it works.  I had to actually call the initializer before setting it using the built-in default copy constructor for my C-Struct.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could:

```
Stream::Stream() : your_init_list {
    lzma_stream tmpStream = LZMA_STREAM_INIT;
    stream_ = tmpStream;
}
```

A constructor has a body like any other function or method, and `struct`s have implicit copy constructors and assignment operators. If you're using GCC, you can even skip the temporary and assign directly to the field.

**Edit:** It's not possible to construct a `struct` in the init list unless it has an appropriate constructor defined (i.e. there is no implicit constructor that takes arguments for every field.) That's why the constructor has a body--so you can do setup for the object that goes beyond basic field assignment.

**Edit #2:** As Ben points out, you can use a helper function for this, but directly initializing the field in the init list (something like `stream_(LZMA_STREAM_INIT)`) isn't possible.

Comment: Ah, I meant in the ctor initializer list. I've already got an init function, so I might as well keep the code together. I'll amend my question...

Comment: Then no, you can't do it there. Don't bother--just do it in the constructor body. That's why it's there. :)

Comment: Actually, that's an interesting side question. Don't some coding standards say to use a separate init function? Why? To make it explicitly clear that things have been initialized, or because there's something about the way ctors can be used that makes the existence of an init function better?

Comment: @zorawar because they're wrong! There's some weird superstition that exceptions are bad, so constructors shouldn't throw, so you shouldn't do anything significant in a constructor but rather have a separate initialisation function that can fail by eg returning false. This is almost never a useful or sensible thing to do.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Is it? You can use a helper function (as illustrated in your answer) but you cannot directly assign the value in the init list.

Comment: @Jonathan: Not until C++0x, anyway.

Comment: @Alan, @Zorawar: The advantage of an init function is being able to reuse it from multiple constructors... and C++0x delegating constructors get rid of that advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the initialization in the ctor?

```
Stream::Stream() : ...
{
    lzma_stream const temp = LZMA_STREAM_INIT;
    stream_ = temp;
    // ...
}
```

Note that you don't need a mem-initializer for `stream_`.  When a POD member has no mem-initializer, C++ will leave it "uninitialized", just like a local variable `lzma_stream stream;`.  But as long as you then assign to it right away, that's not really a bad thing.

I also note that lzma itself recommends this "temp" object assignment pattern (in base.h) for cases when a direct initialization can't be done.  In C, it's talking more about when the `lzma_stream` memory was `malloc`-ed, but it also applies to a C++03 class member.  (C++0x does have a way of doing this in a mem-initializer, yes.)

Comment: Why? See my comment to Jonathan's answer. (I guess, ultimately, because I'm stupid...). I get how the "temp" way is fine, but I'm really wondering if there's any subtlety involved in doing it like that. Is there some exotic uses of classes that will lead me to trouble if I do it like this. (I'll tactfully skirt over the fact that I didn't read that comment in base.h, but in fairness, I did already say that I guessed that'd be the "right" way to do it; not sure if that excuses me, though...)

Comment: @Zorawar: There are sometimes good reasons requiring a public `init()` method.  But most of the time, initialization should go in the constructor and cleanup should go in the destructor, and I avoid public `init()` methods.  Maybe you could ask another Question about that.